# Proving Existence of a Solution to a System of Two Exponential Equations

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, exponential-function, lambert-w

I'm trying to prove that a solution exists to the following system of equations:
$$
\frac{x}{b}=\frac{-e^y(2-e^x-e^y)}{(e^y-1)(e^y-e^x)} \\
\frac{y}{g}=\frac{-e^x(2-e^x-e^y)}{(e^x-1)(e^x-e^y)} 
$$
where $g>0>b$. I don't believe a solution can be expressed in closed form, but I would nevertheless like to show that it exists.

There's a possibility that Lambert's W function is involved, as one can divide the first line by the second, and get an expression which is solvable for $x$ using the Lambert function: $$x=\frac{bye^y}{g(1-e^y)}+\mathbb{W}(Z(y))$$
where $Z(y)=\frac{ybe^{y+\frac{bye^y}{g(e^y-1)}}}{g(e^y-1)}$.